# Python: 'GetContextWebInformation' to udpate SharePoint list item

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, python-requests

I am trying to read/write SharePoint list items through python

I've written below which reads SharePoint details successfully as a response

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings() # suprress all SSL warnings
url = "https://sharepoint.company.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$top=3&$select=ID,Title,Notes" # just reading 3 columns
headers = {'accept': 'application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','Password'), verify=False, stream=True)
```

Now, when I try to update one of the items, I receive `response 403` error

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
json_data = [{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Notes': 'Test Note' }]
response = requests.post(url, { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Notes': 'Test Note' }, headers = self.headers, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','Password'), verify=False)
```

[Microsoft SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest) says `X-RequestDigest: form digest value` has to be sent in headers.

After reading through articles, found the below code to get `form digest value`:

```
site_url = "https://sharepoint.company.com"
login_user = 'domain\\username'
auth = HttpNtlmAuth(login_user, 'PASSWORD')
sharepoint_contextinfo_url = self.site_url + '/_api/contextinfo'
headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'odata': 'verbose',
        'X-RequestForceAuthentication': 'true'
    }
r = requests.post(sharepoint_contextinfo_url, auth=auth, headers=headers, verify=False)
form_digest_value = self.r.json()['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']
```

But, I do not receive `form_digest_value`

I tried to access the `context info` through Browser like `https://sharepoint.company.com/_api/contextinfo` and received below error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'GetContextWebInformation'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use correct HTTP method to invoke the resource.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Can someone please help how to get form digest value? Or is there anyway around to update SharePoint list item?

Thanks in advance!

**Updated**

After going through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/working-with-requestdigest), I can understand we can get __REQUESTDIGEST value from `Page source`. On refreshing the page every min, can see value differs. how can I get the request digest value through python and keep it alive at least for 5mins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer, may be it could help someone

Data passed for update is not done properly here

So, passed like below:

```
json_data = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
    "Title": "updated title from Python"
}
```

and passed `json_data` to requests like below:

```
r= requests.post(api_page, json.dumps(json_data), auth=auth, headers=update_headers, verify=False).text
```

After the above changes, code updated the `Title` on SharePoint.